# gridsearchcv with tfidf and count vectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sentiment-analysis, gridsearchcv

I want to use GridSearchCV for parameter tuning. Is it also possible to check with GridSearchCV whether CountVectorizer or TfidfVectorizer works best? My idea:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
           ('vect', TfidfVectorizer()),
           ('clf', SGDClassifier()),
])
parameters = {
'vect__max_df': (0.5, 0.75, 1.0),
'vect__max_features': (None, 5000, 10000, 50000),
'vect__ngram_range': ((1, 1), (1, 2), (1,3),  
'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False),
'tfidf__norm': ('l1', 'l2', None),
'clf__max_iter': (20,),
'clf__alpha': (0.00001, 0.000001),
'clf__penalty': ('l2', 'elasticnet'),
'clf__max_iter': (10, 50, 80),
}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1, cv=5)
```

My idea: CountVectorizer is the same as TfidfVectorizer with use_idf=False and normalize=None. If GridSearchCV gives this as the best result those parameters, then CountVectorizer is the best option. Is that correct?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've included a given step with its corresponding name in the `Pipeline`, you can access it from the parameter grid and add other parameters, or vectorizers in this case, in the grid. You can also have a list of grids in a single pipeline:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

pipeline = Pipeline([
           ('vect', TfidfVectorizer()),
           ('clf', SGDClassifier()),
])
parameters = [{
    'vect__max_df': (0.5, 0.75, 1.0),
    'vect__max_features': (None, 5000, 10000, 50000),
    'vect__ngram_range': ((1, 1), (1, 2), (1,3),)  
    'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False),
    'tfidf__norm': ('l1', 'l2', None),
    'clf__max_iter': (20,),
    'clf__alpha': (0.00001, 0.000001),
    'clf__penalty': ('l2', 'elasticnet'),
    'clf__max_iter': (10, 50, 80)
},{
    'vect': (CountVectorizer(),)
    # count_vect_params...
    'clf__max_iter': (20,),
    'clf__alpha': (0.00001, 0.000001),
    'clf__penalty': ('l2', 'elasticnet'),
    'clf__max_iter': (10, 50, 80)
}]

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters)
```

Comment: Just curiosity: how is this different from fitting `GridSearchCV` on two different pipelines?

Comment: Well, this really will be having 2 different grids of parameters. I think its cleaner to have a sinlge pipeline though, since there is this possiblity @anddt

Comment: Absolutely, was wondering if this had any practical implication.

Comment: Hi, I was just trying to implement the solution. Since I also include Features Selection with SelectK and several parameters for my classifier resulting in 4608000 fits -> so my program crashed. But in other than that the solution worked for me. Thank you